Subscribe to EventGrid for Defender For Cloud scan results?
I've managed to create an Azure Blob Storage and set up Defender For Cloud. I can see that on uploading it updates the tags for the blob.
I have also been able to set it up to send notifications to an EventGrid topic, and set up a Webhook subscription to an API to receive those notififications.
Now I'm looking to see if, instead of a webhook, I can subscribe and pull events directly from EventGrid from a .NET 8 service.
From reading it doesn't look like EventGrid supports direct pull, only push? If I understand correctly I'd perhaps have to push the EventGrid event to EventHub, and then subscribe and pull via EventHub. Is that right?

have a look at the following feature of the AEG: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/pull-delivery-overview


From reading it doesn't look like EventGrid supports direct pull, only push? If I understand correctly I'd perhaps have to push the EventGrid event to EventHub, and then subscribe and pull via EventHub. Is that right?

Yes, that's correct. You don't stricly need to use Event Hubs, it could be any event streaming or data ingestion system. But, yes, Event Hubs are likely the best option when you want to pull events instead.
If your service is running continuously, you could instead expose an HTTP endpoint and reconfigure the webhook to point to your service. Not sure if this is feasible for you, but it is an option.
